# SQL Customer Order stats based on frequency of order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with this MySQL query to pull some customer stats based on frequency of orders.

I've been given the following criteria:

- Ordered within the last 12 months.
- Ordered three times or more.
- Orders are less than 2 months apart

The first two items I can do no problem, it's the last one.  It also needs to take into account the following:

- Customer may be new and made first purchase only 6 months ago (for example) and would need to calculate from that point.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT c.customers_id, c.customers_firstname, c.customers_email_address, 
    b.biggestOrder AS largest_single_order_in_range,
    b.orders_id AS largest_single_order_id,
    COUNT(o.orders_id) AS order_count_total,
    MAX(o.date_purchased) AS last_order_date,
    MIN(o.date_purchased) AS first_order_date
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN orders_total ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.customers_id = o.customers_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o2.customers_id, o2.orders_id,
        MAX(ot2.`value`) AS biggestOrder
    FROM orders_total ot2
    LEFT JOIN orders o2 ON o2.orders_id = ot2.orders_id
    WHERE
        ot2.class = 'ot_subtotal' AND o2.orders_status = 3
    GROUP BY
        o2.customers_id
) b ON b.customers_id = c.customers_id
WHERE
    ot.class = 'ot_subtotal' AND o.orders_status = 3 
GROUP BY
    b.customers_id
HAVING
    last_order_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
ORDER BY
    last_order_date DESC
```

--Added Table CREATE's (example data/INSERTS to follow):

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_purchased` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_status` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_id`),
  KEY `idx_orders_customers_id` (`customers_id`),
  KEY `idx_orders_status` (`orders_status`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `orders_total` (
  `orders_total_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_total_id`),
  KEY `idx_orders_total_orders_id` (`orders_id`),
  KEY `idx_class` (`class`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customers_firstname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `customers_email_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customers_id`),
  KEY `idx_customers_email_address` (`customers_email_address`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Update:
This comes close but it's not exact, (snippet below is not complete but what would have been added to query at the top).

```
SELECT ...., COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(o.date_purchased)) AS month_count
....
HAVING month_count >= 6
```

But this would only ensure that at least 1 order has been placed in 1 month x 6 minimum which could give results of first 6 months an order has been placed and then nothing for the remaining 6 months and would also exclude customers whose first order was less than 6 months ago.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

To you existing query, add

```
join (
subquery to identify orders within 3 months of each other
) frequentOrders on frequentOrders.customerId = o.customerID
```

that subquery would follow this logic

```
from orders FirstOrder join Orders NextOrder on FirstOrder.CustomerID = NextOrder.CustomerId

where NextOrder.Date_purchased > FirstOrder.DatePurchased
and they are within 3 months of each other
and they are both within the date range of the search
```

I don't work with MySQL so I won't pretend to know the syntax.